# Estimating Concurrent Users - Node.js Heroku MongoLab

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, concurrency, mlab

I am wondering if there is a way or process to correctly estimate the number of concurrent users which my app will be able to support with 2 Dynos on a Node.js (Hapi) based API server using MongoDB hosted on MongoLab (on a shared cluster). I think an important point of consideration (bottle-neck) might also be the fact that the users upload images to Amazon S3 using Cloudinary API. I understand that the answer depends and varies depending on the application and the way users interact with the DB during the game loop. But, is it possible to determine an approximate idea about how many concurrent users will be able to play using the present setup (without scaling up any further). Since, most of the services (other than Amazon S3) are not self-scaling, I was thinking it would be valuable to have an estimate to predict the infrastructure cost.